# Unable to start vscode executable

Tags: executable, crunchbang

I downloaded and extracted the VSCode zip. I see the `Code` binary file, but doubleclicking it in my file manager does nothing. I also tried `./Code` in console, but I only get `bash: ./Code: cannot execute binary file`. Just typing Code causes `bash: Code: command not found`. My guess is that it might be a dependancy issue, but I don't even know where to start.

I tried to chmod 777 the files and folders, but no luck.

uname -a: `Linux crunchbang 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 i686 GNU/Linux`

Running strace produces:

```
$ strace ./Code
execve("./Code", ["./Code"], [/* 25 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76ec000
_llseek(3, 0, 0xbf9d8a88, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb76ec000, 4096)                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Running file produces

```
$ file Code
Code: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7a776e173e68b15269ebd273dd987b526f5ebcae, stripped
```

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio Code on Linux 32-bits](http://superuser.com/questions/908339/visual-studio-code-on-linux-32-bits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution based on another Q&A;

So based on the `file` the Code is a 64bit executable and based on uname my system apparently is 32bit, which is different from what I thought.